# PowerShell foreach select-string query

Tags: powershell

For the CSV file below, I want to search for each type of Fruit in the file and display the last entry via PowerShell. I've tried the following but I'm getting a blank output.

```
$fruits = Import-Csv Fruits.csv | select Fruit | sort-object -Property Fruit -Unique

foreach ($fruit in $fruits)
{
 Import-CSV Fruits.csv | Select-String -Pattern $fruit
}
```

Fruits.csv file:

```
Fruit, Weight
Apple, 3 pounds
Apple, 4 pounds
Apple, 10 pounds
Orange, 3 pounds
Kiwi, 3 pounds
Grape, 2 pounds
Orange, 13 pounds
Grape, 3 pounds
Apple, 6 pounds
Apple, 2 pounds
```

Expected output:

```
Apple, 2 pounds
Orange, 3 pounds
Kiwi, 3 pounds
Grape, 2 pounds
```

Can anyone help in resolving this?

Answer (score 3):

Your expected output is probably *wrong* since last Orange count is **13**.

Anyhow, You can use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group your result based on the `Fruit` property and select the last entry using the `-1` index:

```
Import-Csv Fruits.csv  | 
    Group Fruit |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group[-1]
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Fruit  Weight   
-----  ------   
Apple  2 pounds 
Orange 13 pounds
Kiwi   3 pounds 
Grape  3 pounds
```

Comment: You are welcome. You main issue with your code is that you are using `$fruit` in your `Select-String` cmdlet instead of `$fruit.Fruit` because this way you retrieve the current fruit